# Making sense of `time.Time` values when debugging in Delve

Tags: debugging, go

When debugging a program that processes `time.Time` values, I need to be able to print the values and make sense of them.  In Delve, if I print a variable of type `time.Time` it prints the internal structure of the object, and does not allow me to run `time.Time` methods on the object.

How do I makes sense of this structure and translate it to my normal understanding of what would be printed by the `Unix()`, `UnixNano()`, or `String()` functions.

For example:

```
$ dlv test
(dlv) b calendar.go:200
(dlv) p appt
time.Time {
wall: 0,
ext: 63673770600,
loc: *time.Location {
    name: "Local",
    zone: []time.zone len: 4, cap: 4, [
        (*time.zone)(0xc0000a8100),
    ],
    tx: []time.zoneTrans len: 235, cap: 235, [
        (*time.zoneTrans)(0xc0000bb000),
        ...+171 more
    ],
    cacheStart: 1520751600,
    cacheEnd: 1541311200,
    cacheZone: *(*time.zone)(0xc0000a8100),},}
```

Or in the case of a list of values:

```
(dlv) p dates
[]time.Time len: 2, cap: 2, [
{
    wall: 0,
    ext: 63673689600,
    loc: *(*time.Location)(0xc00008e9c0),},
{
    wall: 0,
    ext: 63673776000,
    loc: *(*time.Location)(0xc00008ea80),},
]
```

I found [a github ticket to add pretty-printing of `time.Time` values](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/issues/999) to Delve.  Until that is approved and released, what can I do to make sense of these values and translate them to a more readable form?

As a workaround, I considered adding new variables of string type that I would update (as needed) with the output of `.String()` or `.Format(...)`.  Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [the issue](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/999) adding the functionality you're wanting has been closed.

> Closing, you can instead call methods on the time value to format via
>   the call t.Format(...) or call t.String().